# Ionic 2 data saving on browser but not on device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have a restaurant reservation app in which it takes event dates from a calendar ,saves them in an array which are then passed on to a page to generate cards from the array data. My problem is that the data is saved on web but on device it is not saved.here is my code:

```
//saving of event data
    let eventData=data;

      eventData.startTime= new Date(data.startTime);
      eventData.endTime= new Date(data.endTime);


        let events=this.eventSource;
        events.push(eventData);
        this.eventSource=[] ;
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.eventSource=events;
        });

          this.nativeStorage.getItem('data1').then((data)=>{
            if(data !==null){
            // events.push(eventData);
              this.nativeStorage.setItem('data1',events);
              console.log(events);

            }
          })
```

And i generate the cards like so:

```
export class CardsPage {
items:any;
  constructor(public nativeStorage: NativeStorage,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public storage:Storage) {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('data1').then((data)=>{
      this.items=data;
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CardsPage');
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('data1').then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);

    })
  }

}
```

The card design is as so:

```
<ion-content >
    <ion-card *ngFor='let item of items'>
        <ion-card-header>
```

//title gotten from array for test purposes

```
          {{item.title}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
         <p>

         </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

I would greatly appreciate your take on this issue

Comment: did you check the console for any errors. connect your device and open chrome://inspect/#devices in chrome see your connected device in remote target  , click on inpect to check logs

Comment: this.nativeStorage.setItem will only be called if getItem receives anything.

Comment: you can also implement the error handler of the promises to see if there is an underlying issue like explained here (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/)

Comment: Hey guys,thanks for the assist .Found the solution to the problem. Apparently the emulator storage was not configured as it should hence the issue.